# How do I count modified lines of code?

Tags: c#, levenshtein-distance, lines-of-code

I have a program which counts lines of code (excluding comments, braces, whitespace, etc.) of two programs then compares them. It puts all the lines from one program in one List and the lines from the other program in another List. It then removes all lines that are identical between the two. One List is then all the lines added to program 1 to get program 2 and the other List is all the lines removed from program 1 to get program 2.

Now I need a way to detect how many lines of code from program 1 have been MODIFIED to get program 2. I found an algorithm for the Levenshtein Distance, and it seems like that will work. I just need to compare the distance with the length of the strings to get a percentage changed, and I'll need to come up with a good value for the threshold.

However my problem is this: how do I know which two strings to compare for the Levenshtein Distance? My best guess is to have a nested for loop and loop through one program once for every line in the other program to compare every line with every other line looking for a Distance that meets my difference threshold. However, that seems very inefficient. Are there any other ways of doing this?

I should add this is for a software engineering class. It's technically homework, but we're allowed to use any resource we need. While I'm just looking for an algorithm, I'll let you know I'm using C#.

Comment: Wouldn't your answer just be the sum of both lists? what ever remains in list 1 was deleted, and what remains in list 2 was added. Am I missing something? I dunno, define "line of code".

Comment: A line of code is any line that has a semicolon (and isn't a comment), plus some other lines like method headers and lines containing reserved words like for, while, try, etc. A modified line is a line in program 2 that is very similar but not identical to a line in program 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you allow lines to be shuffled, how do you count the changes? Not all shuffled lines might result in identical functionality, even if you compare all lines and find exact matches.

If you compare

```
var random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 50);
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  var random = new Random();
  int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 50);
}
```

you have four *unchanged* lines of code, but the second version is likely to produce different results. There is *definitely* a change in the code, and yet line-by-line comparison will not detect it if you allow shuffling.

This is a good reason to disallow shuffling and actually mark line 1 in the first code as deleted, and line 2 in the second code as added, even though the deleted line and the added line are exactly the same.

Once you dicide that lines cannot be shuffled, i think you can figure out quite easily how to match your lines for comparison.

To step through both sources and compare the line you might want to look up the balance line algorithm (e.g http://www.isqa.unomaha.edu/haworth/isqa3300/fs006.htm )

Answer (score 0):

If you suggest that lines of codes are shuffled (their order can be changed) then you need to compare all lines from 1st program to all lines from 2nd program excluding not changed lines.

You can simplify you task suggesting that lines cannot be shuffled. They can be only inserted, removed or unchanged. From my experience most of the programs comparing text files work this way

Comment: I hadn't thought about restricting it to only non-shuffled lines. I'll have to decide if that's what I want. Thanks for the answer and suggestion!